# Why Date object @@toPrimitive default value is toString?

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion, type-coercion

Other object @@toPrimitive(default) first look object.valueOff() and if valueOff return object itself look object.toString method. But in date object this is different. This is interesting for me is this have reason?

Comment: Because backward-compatibility with the inconsistencies of web implementations.

Comment: I dont understand this answer can explain your sentence?

Comment: And also I think valueOff value usefill than toString method in Date object

Comment: In short, that's how it always has been and since code on the web depends on this, it's too late to change and remove the inconsistency. No other reason.

Comment: I understand this is like typeof Null problem :d Thanks for response.

Comment: But this occupy my mind.

Comment: For example + operator in objects trigger default conversion modes. But İ think this doesn't make any sense. İf Date object @@primitive default conversion mode will be number. + operator can be trigger number conversion mode all objects.